# command Line input as a Binary Number

Tags: c, command-line

I am not using this anywhere, while working with other programs I got a doubt. How to pass a binary number as command line parameter and what functions are available to convert to integer?

Example:

```
./HelloWorld b1010
```

above code I want to read as integer 10. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) with a base of 2. Remove/check the b character first.